# Anonymous inner class members not being accessible, in java

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-class, anonymous-inner-class

When i use anonymous inner classes to create Nodes. When i print all the keys, they are printing as 0's, instead of the values i assigned in the anonymous class declaration. Am i doing something wrong? Here's my code:

```
public class LinkedListTest {
Node head;

public void addInOrder(final int value) {
    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node() {
            int key = value;
        };
    }
    else if(head.key > value) {
        final Node temp = head;
        head = new Node() {
            int key = value;
            Node next = temp;
        };
    }
    else {
        Node theNode = head;
        while(theNode.key < value) {
            if (theNode.next == null) {
                theNode.next = new Node() {
                    int key = value;
                };
                return;
            }
            else if(theNode.next.key > value) {
                final Node temp = theNode.next;
                theNode.next = new Node() {
                    int key = value;
                    Node next = temp;
                };
                return;
            }
            theNode = theNode.next;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my class declaration for my Node:

```
class Node {
    int key;
    Node next;
}
```

And this is my printing method:

```
  public void printAll(Node hasNode) {
    if (hasNode != null) {
        System.out.println(hasNode.key);
        if (hasNode.next != null) {
            printAll(hasNode.next);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because you aren't assigning values to the fields in `Node`, you are assigning values to the fields in the anonymous subclass with the same names.

Add a constructor to `Node`, and don't create an anonymous subclass:

```
class Node {
  int key;
  Node next;

  Node(int key, Node next) {
    this.key = key; this.next = next;
  }
}
```

Optionally, you can add a second constructor which just takes the key:

```
  Node(int key) {
    this(key, null);
  }
```

The alternative is just calling `new Node(key, null)`.

Comment: Andy beat me by a few seconds :-), but yes, this is what's happening. The `int key = value;` in the anonymous subclass is declaring and initializing an instance variable in the anonymous subclass that's overriding the field of the same name in `Node`.

Comment: I understand, but whats the point of an anonymous inner class if the values fields i assign to them can't be accessed outside of the scope their declared in? I thought 'shadowing' would work in this instance.

Thanks for the feedback as well!

Comment: There are many uses for anonymous inner classes that don't involve declaring member variables of the same name. However, any member variable or non-overriding method declared inside the anonymous inner class is (almost) inaccessible, since you simply have a reference to a `Node`, not `LinkedListTest$1`, the specific subclass of `Node`.

Comment: (The "almost" is because you could access them like `new Node() { int foo = 5; }.foo`; but that's a pretty unusual and not-very-useful thing to do)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know members were basically inaccessible when using anonymous inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

As Andy Turner answered, you declared `key` and `next` in your anonymous class as instance variables of the anonymous class, and you are initializing those instance variables, but they are unrelated to the instance variables of the same name from the class `Node`.

If it would make it easier to understand, this:

```
theNode.next = new Node() {
    int key = value;
    Node next = temp;
};
```

is equivalent to a local class like this:

```
class Foo extends Node {
    int key = value;
    Node next = temp;
};
theNode.next = new Foo();
```

or you can even lift the class out of the method so the capturing is more clear:

```
// outside the method
class Foo extends Node {
    int key;
    Node next;
    Foo(int value, Node temp) { key = value; next = temp; }
};
// inside the method
theNode.next = new Foo(value, temp);
```

The point is, in all of these cases, you are assigning values to the instance variables of `Foo`, and not the instance variables of `Node`.

It is possible for you to perform initialization in the anonymous class that allows you to assign to the instance variables of `Node`. Although anonymous classes don't have constructors (they don't need them), initialization can be done in the instance initializer:

```
theNode.next = new Node() {
    {
        key = value;
        next = temp;
    }
};
```

It's often written in the "double brace initialization" style:

```
theNode.next = new Node() {{
    key = value;
    next = temp;
}};
```